# how to inject bean dependency in class extending GlobalSettings in play framework 2.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a class which extends GlobalSettings, I want to inject another bean in that am not getting how to do it. While googling I come to know about using @javax.inject.Inject but this didn't work and am getting null reference. Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Thanks,
Pradeep Sharma

Comment: It's recommended to move away from using GlobalSettings from Play 2.4 onwards; which methods are you overriding?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for play 2.3 (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal), whatever thing extends GlobalSettings must be an object. Therefore, dependency injection is not really possible.

What you could do would be to use the injector directly to obtain an instance of a dependency - container managed class:

```
val myComponent = Play.current.injector.instanceOf[MyComponent]
```

However, not only is this particular mechanism to obtain an instance discourged, using GlobalSettings is discouraged altogether as of play 2.4 (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings). With this guide, you should be able to refactor the structure of your code in a way that allows you to do real dependency injection.

As an example, you may want to take a look at the HttpRequestHandler (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpRequestHandlers):

```
class SimpleHttpRequestHandler @Inject() (router: Router) extends HttpRequestHandler {
```